404 not found , function in symfony
 public function forgetPassword($request)
    {
        $email = $request->get('email');
        $user = $this->em->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['username' => $email]);
        if (!$user) {
            return [
                'status' => 400,
                'data' => 'You don\'t have account with this email'
            ];
        }
        $newpassword = $this->generateUniqueCode();

        $globalUtils = new GlobalUtils();
        $globalUtils->SendForgotPasswordEmail($this->mailer, $email, [
            'subject' => 'New password to ' . $user->getUsername() . ' ',
            'newPassword' => $newpassword
        ]);
        $user->setPassword(
            $this->passwordHasher->hashPassword(
                $user,
                $newpassword
            )
        );

        $this->em->flush();
        return [
            'status' => 200,
            'data' => ['New password has send to your email!']
        ];
    }

The function functions properly on localhost, but I receive a 404 Not Found problem when I try it on prod. I initially believed the problem to be with the path as I use "/v1/user/forgotPassword" on both localhost and prod but the path look fine for me. So why i get the 404 not found error?

I look into it and find that the mailer is the problem.
